# Looping through posts per category gives same posts for each category

Tags: posts, loop, query, transient

For a specific section on my website I loop through some categories and get the three latest posts in that categorie and list them. Like so:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('exclude' => '1, 4, 9, 10, 2899')); ?>

<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
    <div class="subject">
        <h3><?php echo $category->cat_name; ?></h3>
        <ul>
            <?php $args = array(
                'cat' => $category->cat_ID,
                'posts_per_page' => 3
            ); ?>
            <?php if (false === ( $category_posts_query = get_transient( 'category_posts' ) ) ) {
                $category_posts_query = new WP_Query($args);
                set_transient( 'category_posts', $category_posts_query, 36 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
            }
            ?>
            <?php while($category_posts_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php $category_posts_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

However, the result is not what is expected: all posts are the same across categories even though the posts don't belong to the different categories:
[image]

When I remove the `transient` for caching, everything works as expted.

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('exclude' => '1, 4, 9, 10, 2899')); ?>

<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
    <div class="subject">
        <h3><?php echo $category->cat_name; ?></h3>
        <ul>
            <?php $args = array(
                'cat' => $category->cat_ID,
                'posts_per_page' => 3
            ); ?>
            <?php $category_posts_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
            <?php while($category_posts_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php $category_posts_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How do I add chacing to this last snippet?

Comment: I have added extra important info to my question. Please check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need so many transients set, one for each category. You can only use one, that is enough. Transients are quite expensive to set as it requires additional db queries, so you would want to cut down on the use.

As always, I like to keep my templates simple, short and sweet, so I tend to write custom functions to move the bulk of the code outside my templates. You can put everything in one function with one transient

You can try something like this (*Requires PHP 5.4+*)

```
function get_term_post_list( $taxonomy = 'category', $args = [], $query_args = [] )  
{
    /*
     * Check if we have a transient set
     */
    if ( false === ( $output = get_transient( 'term_list_' . md5( $taxonomy . json_encode( $args ) . json_encode( $query_args ) ) ) ) ) {

        /*
         * Use get_terms to get an array of terms
         */
        $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

       if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) )
            return null;

        /*
         * We will create a string with our output
         */
        $output = ''; 
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            $output .= '<div class="subject">';
            $output .= '<h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';
            $output .= '<ul>';

            /*
             * Use a tax_query to make this dynamic for all taxonomies
             */
            $default_args = [
                'no_found_rows' => true,
                'suppress_filters' => true,
                'tax_query' => [
                    [
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'terms' => $term->term_id,
                        'include_children' => false
                    ]
                ]
            ];
            /*
             * Merge the tax_query with the user set arguments
             */
            $merged_args = array_merge( $default_args, $query_args );

            $q = new WP_Query( $merged_args );

            while($q->have_posts()) {
                $q->the_post();

                $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title() ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title() ) . '</a></li>';

            }
            wp_reset_postdata();

            $output .= '</ul>';
            $output .= '</div>';

        }
        /*
         * Set our transient, use all arguments to create a unique key for the transient name
         */
        set_transient( 'term_list_' . md5( $taxonomy . json_encode( $args ) . json_encode( $query_args ) ), $output, 36 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }
    /*
     * $output will be atring, treat as such
     */
    return $output;
}
```

### FEW NOTES

- The first parameter, $taxonomy is the taxonomy to get terms and posts from. It defaults to 'category'
- The second parameter is `$args` which is the arguments which should be passed to `get_terms()`. For more info, check [`get_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)
- The third parameter, `$query_args` is the arguments that should be passed to the custom query. Remember to avoid using any taxonomy related parameters. For more info, see [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
- If the second parameter is not set and the third parameter is set, pass an empty array to the second parameter
- Modify and abuse the code as you see fit

### USAGE

You can now use the function as follow in your templates

```
$post_list = get_term_post_list( 'category', ['exclude' => '1, 4, 9, 10, 2899'], ['posts_per_page' => 3] );
if ( $post_list !== null ) {
    echo $post_list;
}
```

If you do not pass anything to the second parameter but to the third, you should do the following (pass empty array)

```
$post_list = get_term_post_list( 'category', [], ['posts_per_page' => 3] );
if ( $post_list !== null ) {
    echo $post_list;
}
```

### EDIT

In a rush, I totally forgot to add a function to flush the transient when a new post is published, updated, deleted or undeleted. As your code stands, the list will only be updated when the transient expires.

To flush the transient on the above post conditions, simply use the `transition_post_status` hook. Add the following to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ()
{
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%_term_list_%')" );
        $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_timeout%_term_list_%')" );
});
```

### EDIT 2

From your comment to this answer

> As you might have guessed I'd liked to use this in combination [with my other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/185011/31545). How would I go about doing that? Should the exclusion of the terms happen in `get_term_post_list()`? Or should the two functions be merged somehow? (As I don't need them seperately.)

The best way to accomplish is to merge the two functions into one. That would make the most sense. I have merged the two functions and modified the functionality with the exclude parameters. What I have done is, you can now add an array of term id's to excludse via the `get_terms()` `exclude` parameter and you can also within the same function set an array of term slugs to exclude. The results will be merged into one single `exclude` parameter before being passed to `get_terms()`

Here is the function, again I have commented it well to make it easy to follow (*This goes into functions.php*)

```
function get_term_post_list( $taxonomy = 'category', $args = [], $query_args = [], $exclude_by_slug = [] )  
{
    /*
     * Check if we have a transient set
     */
    if ( false === ( $output = get_transient( 'term_list_' . md5( $taxonomy . json_encode( $args ) . json_encode( $query_args ) ) ) ) ) {

        /*
         * Check if any array of slugs is passed and if it is a valid array
         */
        if ( is_array( $exclude_by_slug ) && !empty( $exclude_by_slug ) ) {

            foreach ( $exclude_by_slug as $value ) {

                /*
                 * Use get_term_by to get the term ID and add ID's to an array
                 */
                $term_objects = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy );
                $term_ids[] = (int) $term_objects->term_id;

            }

        }

        /*
         * Merge $args['exclude'] and $term_ids 
         */
        if ( isset( $args['exclude'] ) && isset( $term_ids ) ) {

            $excluded_args = (array) $args['exclude'];
            unset( $args['exclude'] );
            $args['exclude'] = array_merge( $excluded_args, $term_ids );

        } elseif ( !isset( $args['exclude'] ) && isset( $term_ids ) ) {

            $args['exclude'] = $term_ids;

        } 

        /*
         * Use get_terms to get an array of terms
         */
        $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

       if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) )
            return null;

        /*
         * We will create a string with our output
         */
        $output = ''; 
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            $output .= '<div class="subject">';
            $output .= '<h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';
            $output .= '<ul>';

            /*
             * Use a tax_query to make this dynamic for all taxonomies
             */
            $default_args = [
                'no_found_rows' => true,
                'suppress_filters' => true,
                'tax_query' => [
                    [
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'terms' => $term->term_id,
                        'include_children' => false
                    ]
                ]
            ];
            /*
             * Merge the tax_query with the user set arguments
             */
            $merged_args = array_merge( $default_args, $query_args );

            $q = new WP_Query( $merged_args );

            while($q->have_posts()) {
                $q->the_post();

                $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title() ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title() ) . '</a></li>';

            }
            wp_reset_postdata();

            $output .= '</ul>';
            $output .= '</div>';

        }
        /*
         * Set our transient, use all arguments to create a unique key for the transient name
         */
        set_transient( 'term_list_' . md5( $taxonomy . json_encode( $args ) . json_encode( $query_args ) ), $output, 36 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }
    /*
     * $output will be string, treat as such
     */
    return $output;
}
```

As far as usage, you first need to look at the parameters that you can pass

- Parameter 1 - `$taxonomy` -> taxonomy to get terms from. Default `category`
- Parameter 2 - `$args` -> The arguments that should be passed to `get_terms()`. Please see [`get_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) for a full list of parameters that can be passed as an array. Default empty array `[]`
- Parameter 3 - `$query_args` -> Custom argument to be passed to `WP_Query`. You should not pass taxonomy related parameters here as it cause issues with the deafult build in `tax_query`. For a full list of valid arguments which can be passed in an array, see [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Default empty array `[]`
- Parameter 4 - `$exclude_by_slug` -> An array of slugs to exclude. Please note, this has to be a valid array for this to work. Strings will be ignored. Default empty array `[]`

You can now call the function in any of your template files as

```
$a = get_term_post_list( 'category', ['exclude' => [1, 13, 42]], ['posts_per_page' => 3], ['term-slug-1', 'term-slug-2'] );
echo $a;
```

OR

```
$taxonomy = 'category';
$args = [
    'exclude' => [1, 13, 42]
];
$query_args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 3
];
$exclude_by_slug = [
    '0' => ['term-slug-1', 'term-slug-2']
];
$a = get_term_post_list( $taxonomy, $args, $query_args, $exclude_by_slug );
echo $a;
```

Final note, if you don't need to pass a specific parameter, remember to just pass an empty array like

```
$a = get_term_post_list( 'category', [], [], ['term-slug-1'] );
echo $a;
```

All the above replaces all your code in your question

Comment: What if user adds a new term ? They have to wait 3 days to get visible on page ?

Comment: That is easy, flush your transient once a new post is published, will update my answer :-)

Comment: Great! Now this is perfect.

Comment: @Sumit updated with the specific info. Thank for poiting that out. Totally forgot about that. Got really caught up last night between answers. ;-)

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts! Especially your way of commenting everything thoroughly. It really helps a beginner like myself! I am a little confused on how to use this though. As you might have guessed I'd liked to use this in combination [with my other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185011/exclude-category-by-slug-for-for-each-loop). How would I go about doing that? Should the exclusion of the terms happen in `get_term_post_list()`? Or should the two functions be merged somehow? (As I don't need them seperately.)

Comment: @BramVanroy The best will be to merge the two. The problem you are facing now is, are you going to exclude terms by id and slug. If so, some parts of other function needs rewriting to accomplish this. I'm tied up a bit, so I cannot code till later today. Please let me know about term exclude issue

Comment: No, I'll only be excluding by slug. Thanks for your efforts so far

Comment: @BramVanroy Please see my update. I have merged the two functions, hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Tested and approved! I wish I could give you more than only an accept, but SE doesn't allow for donations or tips unfortunately. :D Thanks a lot! I am reading through the code and I wonder about one thing, what's the advantage of `apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title() ) ` over `echo get_the_title()`?

Comment: My pleasure, glad it works. Just one request, would you please accept my answer to your other question as well as these two are linked :-). The advantage of `apply_filters()` is that it applies all the relevant filters to `get_the_title()`. Remember, `get_the_title()` is unfiltered, it basically just returns unfiltered `$post->post_title`. Because our functions return its output, so we need to return the title with `get_the_title()`. Using `the_title()` which is already filtered will have unexpected output

Comment: This goes for `get_the_content()` as well @BramVanroy

Comment: My pleasure, of to enjoy the weekend now. Enjoy yours. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your category is ID being changed at every loop iteration and you are setting a common transient, which gives the same result every time even if category ID has been changed.

So you need to save transient for every category.

```
set_transient( 'category_posts_' . $category->cat_ID, $category_posts_query, 36 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
```

Try this solution

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('exclude' => '1, 4, 9, 10, 2899')); ?>

<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
    <div class="subject">
        <h3><?php echo $category->cat_name; ?></h3>
        <ul>
            <?php $args = array(
                'cat' => $category->cat_ID,
                'posts_per_page' => 3
            ); ?>
            <?php if (false === ( $category_posts_query = get_transient( 'category_posts_' . $category->cat_ID ) ) ) {
                $category_posts_query = new WP_Query($args);
                set_transient( 'category_posts_' . $category->cat_ID, $category_posts_query, 36 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
            }
            ?>
            <?php while($category_posts_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php $category_posts_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Add the whole list in **one** transient. Setting transients on every iteration is very expensive