# Exclude category by slug for for each loop

Tags: loop, slug, categories

I am trying to exclude some categories from a for-loop.

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('exclude' => 'apps, windows')); ?>

<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
    // the_loop
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Even though no error is thrown, it doesn't work: all categories are used in the loop. How can I exclude some categories by slug?

I am working with multiple sites that have different cat IDs but the same slug, so I need to filter by slug rather than by cat ID.

---

For future readers: Pieter Goosen answered this question and another in into a merged answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185048/16574).

Comment: `exclude` takes a comma separated string of ascending category ID's

Comment: @PieterGoosen I'm aware of that, but because I am working with multiple sites that have different cat IDs but the same slug, I need to filter by slug rather than by cat ID.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, I will post one a bit later. Leaving work now, so give me about 2 hours :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already stated, straight from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

> **exclude**
>
> (string) Excludes one or more categories from the list generated by wp_list_categories. This parameter takes a comma-separated list of categories by unique ID, in ascending order

As you have stated, you have to use the category slug. To make this possible and dynamic, I think the best will be to write your own wrapper function to achieve this. We are going to use [`get_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) (which is used by [`get_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) internally) to get our categories and [`get_term_by()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) to get the category ID so that we can pass that to `get_terms()`

Here is the function, I have commented it well for better understanding (*Requires PHP 5.4+*)

```
function exclude_term_by( $taxonomy = 'category', $args = [], $exclude = [] )
{
    /*
     * If there are no term slugs to exclude or if $exclude is not a valid array, return get_terms
     */
    if ( empty( $exclude ) || !is_array( $exclude ) )
        return get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

    /*
     * If we reach this point, then we have terms to exclude by slug
     * Simply continue the process. 
     */ 
    foreach ( $exclude as $value ) {

            /*
             * Use get_term_by to get the term ID and add ID's to an array
             */
            $term_objects = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy );
            $term_ids[] = (int) $term_objects->term_id;

    }

    /*
     * Set up the exclude parameter with an array of ids from $term_ids
     */
    $excluded_ids = [
        'exclude' => $term_ids
    ];

    /*
     * Merge the user passed arguments $args with the excluded terms $excluded_ids
     * If any value is passed to $args['exclude'], it will be ignored
     */
    $merged_arguments = array_merge( $args, $excluded_ids );

    /*
     * Lets pass everything to get_terms
     */
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $merged_arguments ); 

    /*
     * Return the results from get_terms
     */
    return $terms;
}
```

Before I go into usage, here are a few notes

- The first parameter, `$taxonomy` is the particular taxonomy to pass to `get_terms()` inside the function, it defaults to `category`
- The second parameter, `$args` takes the same parameters as `get_terms()`. Just a note, if the third parameter is set, the default `exclude` parameter's value is ignored if anything is passed to it. This value will be overridden by whatever is passed to `$exclude`. If nothing is passed to this parameter, and anything is passed to `$exclude`, you need to pass an empty array as value
- The third parameter, `$excludes` takes an array of term slugs which should be excluded. If the value is not a valid array, `get_terms()` will be returned without excluding the necessary terms, so be sure to pass an array of slugs
- Treat the output from the function in the same way you would with `get_terms()`. Remember, you should also check for empty values and `WP_Error` objects before using the value from the function
- Modify and abuse the code as you see fit

Now for the usage in your template files. Note the empty array passed to the `$args` parameter if anything is passed to the `$exclude` parameter

```
$terms = exclude_term_by( 'category', [], ['term-slug-one', 'term-slug-two'] );
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    ?><pre><?php var_dump($terms); ?></pre><?php
}
```

For any extra info on usage, see `get_terms()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a small error on your first line of code. You should separate 'each' category with quotes in the array. So the first line should be:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('exclude' => 'apps', 'windows')); ?>
```

Comment: Check my comment to OP. You should use ID's, not slug